# log4j2.properties cannot read variables from Docker Environment or Kubernetes Env

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, log4j2

In Spring Boot 2.6.0 using Log4J2. I want to use env variables from external to log4j.propeties
but it is always taking local `application.propeties` file instead of real docker or Kubernetes env variables

File `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=myapp

#Logger FilePath
log.file.path=logs/dev/my-app
```

Docker Composer File

```
   version: "3"

services:
 
  spring-app-log4j2:
    build: ./log4j2
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=80
      - LOG_FILE_PATH=logs/prod/my-app
```

File `log4j2.properties`

```
name=config

#Read Properties values from application properties
property.filename = ${bundle:application:log.file.path}

property.layoutPattern = %d{MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z} | ${hostName} | %-5p | %c{1}:%L  |  %M() - %m%n

appenders=console, rolling 

#log to console
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=${layoutPattern}


#log to file and daily rolling
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = roll
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${filename}.%d{dd-MMM-yyyy}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = ${layoutPattern}
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = roll


rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout,rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = roll
```

Output Tried

```
 property.filename = ${bundle:application:logpath}     #Output - logs/dev/app
    #(Taking values from application Properties only, not taking from Docker pod environment varibales)
    property.filename = ${sys:logpath}     #Output - ${sys:logpath}
    property.filename = ${env:logpath}   # Not Working   #Output - ${env:logpath}
    #use filename variable 
    appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}.log
```

When Printing inside Java code

```java
@Value("${logpath}") String logpath;  #Output -logs/prod/app
# Working with Docker env
```

Problem : When log4j initiated it is not finding the file path from environment , so by default reading from application.propeties

How can i read from Docker environment or Kubernetes Environment

i need log file should "logs/prod/my-app" instead of "logs/dev/my-app"

Src Code : https://github.com/jeebendu/log4j2

Comment: I'd like to replicate this issue locally but there is some information missing. Could you please share example code application of your app, Docker file and yaml files that you are applying in the Kubernets so your [issue will be reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS.
I have updated my minimal code here , can you try once 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your attempts you use a single source for the `filename` property. You need to use one of the *fallback* features of variable substitution:

- You can add a default value to your variable substitution using the syntax `${variable:-default}`:

  ```
  property.filename = ${env:LOG_FILE_PATH:-${bundle:application:log.file.path}}
  appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}.log
  ```
- or you can exploit the fact that every `${prefix:variable}` falls back to `${variable}`:

  ```
  property.LOG_FILE_PATH = ${bundle:application:log.file.path}
  appender.rolling.fileName = ${env:LOG_FILE_PATH}
  ```